# Is there an unbounded function with a bounded derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, bounded-variation

I know that there exists bounded functions with unbounded derivatives. For example, $\sin(e^x)$ is bounded and differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, but its derivative is unbounded.

Is it possible for an unbounded function to have a bounded derivative?

Comment: $f(x) = x$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: it's possible, although then the domain has to be unbounded

Answer (score 5):

Yes, $f(x)=x$ whereas $f'(x)=1$.

Having seen the competition in here answering with the simplest possible function, why not define the function
$$
f(x)=\int\sin(\ln(x))dx=-\frac{1}{2}x\cdot\left(\cos(\ln(x))-\sin(\ln(x))\right)
$$
with its derivative
$$
f'(x)=\sin(\ln(x))\in[-1,1]
$$
Since $x$ is not bounded and $\cos(t)-\sin(t)=1$ whenever $t$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ and the equation $\ln(x)=t$ has solutions for all $t$ we see that $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x$ for an unbounded set of $x$-values thus being unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider $f\left(x\right)=x$. It is not bounded, but its derivative is constant, hence bounded.